# How can I tell when I've loaded TinyMCE v6 on an unsupported browser?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-6

I see [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/6.0-release-notes-core-changes/) that TinyMCE version 6 does not support Internet Explorer 11. So how can I tell when somebody tries to load it on IE11?

If I load `tinymce.min.js` in IE11 then look for the resulting global `tinymce` object, will it exist? Will it have some error attribute?

I have a whole bunch of js code that I don't want to run if TinyMCE isn't supported.

(I do not have a copy of IE11 to test with, so forgive me for asking this sort of dumb question!)